# Добавление элемента в массив

Tags: c#, массивы

Имеется массив `object[,] array = null;`. Нужно добавить в него `chk` по индексу `[x, y]`.

Пытался вот так: `array[x, y] = chk;`, но это не срабатывает (`NullReferenceException`).

Как добавить элемент в массив?

Comment: Как добавить элемент в неинициализированный массив? Никак.

Comment: @Илья Что такое chk?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если говорить очень просто, то есть полка для хранения массива и есть сам массив.

Полка `object[,] array` у Вас есть, но вот только на ней нет самого массива (`null`). Поэтому прежде чем положить что-то в массив на полке, надо убедиться, что на этой полке он есть.
Положите на полку сам массив, причем такой, чтобы его размеры были никак не меньше `x + 1, y + 1`: `array = new Object[x + 1, y + 1];`.

А ещё лучше возьмите книгу или руководство из интернета и прочитайте о том, как создаются и применяются массивы.

Answer (score 1):

Если ваши объекты имеют определенный тип (например, CheckBox), то лучше использовать типизированный массив:

```
var array = new CheckBox[x, y];
array[x-1, y-1] = new CheckBox();
```

Если в массив нужно будет класть и другие контроллы, то можно воспользоваться базаовым классом:

```
var array = new Control[x, y];
array[x-1, y-1] = new CheckBox();
```